# Find all divs with a span id that contains any of a matching list of words

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to write a little script to add a class based on whether or not a list item's span id contains any of the words in a list of words.

The list has the basic structure:

```
<div id="main_list">
    <li class>
        <a data-item_number_id="555000" class="item"  <span id="displayname">greyblackhammer</span></a>
    <li class>
        <a data-item_number_id="555002" class="item"  <span id="displayname">grey_green_hammer</span></a>
    <li class>
        <a data-item_number_id="555004" class="item"  <span id="displayname">red_orangehammer</span></a>
```

With thousands of entries.

Let's say I have:

```
var list_of_words = ["Green", "black", "other_words"]
```

I want to be able to search through the list of span ids (they can contain any mixture of spaces, upper and lowercase, underscores, etc), and, if they contain any of the strings in my list of words, add a "starred" class to their parent, so - in this example it would be:

```
 <div id="main_list">
    <li class ="starred">
        <a data-item_number_id="555000" class="item"  <span id="displayname">greyblackhammer</span></a>
    <li class="starred">
        <a data-item_number_id="555002" class="item"  <span id="displayname">grey_green_hammer</span></a>
    <li class>
        <a data-item_number_id="555002" class="item"  <span id="displayname">red_orangehammer</span></a>
```

So, case doesn't matter, spacing doesn't matter - just whether or not the span id contains the desired string in some way.

I'm not that familiar with jQuery, so I haven't gotten very far. Here's what I have:

```
 ids_to_star = ["Green", "black"];

 function star_matching_span_ids(){

var matching_ids = $('#main_list').find("div:contains(ids_to_star)");
   $.each(matching_ids, function (){
       $(this).parent('li').addClass('starred');
   });
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work...it doesn't even correctly select the span ids. Hopefully you kind folks can point me in the right direction.

Comment: id's must be unique on a page.

Comment: My bad, I copied and pasted the example line and forgot to change it. The ids are all unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your HTML and JS:

1. In your HTML the `a` and `li` tag are not closed.
2. In your javascript you only declared the function and did not call it, so in that case is not gonna work.
3. To look for with the `find` function would be recomendable to look for in the items one up in the hierarchy, it means select the `a` elements and apply find function to these, additional you must to put a word into the `contains` word not an array, here an example:

   ```
   ids_to_star = ["green", "black"];

   function star_matching_span_ids(){

   var matching_ids = $('').find("div:contains("+ids_to_star[0]+")");
      $.each(matching_ids, function (){
         $(this).parent('li').addClass('starred');
      });
   }
   ```

Here an example of you need working: https://jsbin.com/donuzozemo/1/edit?html,js,output